# How could I make test for check correctness of annotation @Listen in Zkoss?

Tags: testing, model-view-controller, junit, event-handling, zk

I made a mistake in annotation `@Listen` in Zkoss framework. How could I make JUnit test for this purpose? I know how to make integration tests, but I want to test without applicationserver.

Example:

```
@Listen("onClick = #searchButton; onOK = #keywordBox ;onOK = #recordCount")
```

`keywordBox` must be changed to `searchButton`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I have with ZK. And I find it much worse in their MVVM approach where most everything ends up in text.

To be able to assert that the listener is wired up as you expect, you need ZK to do the wiring first. This can be done without spinning up your own application server using [ZK's Application Test (ZATs)](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zats) project. It's pretty straightforward to set up and does the trick.

Comment: ZATS use jetty(Jetty provides a Web server and javax.servlet container and many other integrations) and Rhino(Rhino is an open source JavaScript engine.).What is the point to use it if I have integration test on the same contaniner?

Comment: Like I said, you can avoid spinning up *your own* server. But yes, it does create a server under the hood - no way to avoid that. ZATs has the advantage of handling boiler plate stuff for you, but most importantly, gives you utilities to easily access the components on the site and verify their state. This is less straightforward to do in your own integration tests.